# Cannot make a disk image with disk utility Status 27

Tags: disk-utility, recovery

I'm trying to take a disk image of a MacBook Pro 2012 with an SSD and OS X El Capitan installed.
I went into Recovery Mode and selected my partition and the target is an external HDD.

First I got error status 2, but then I remembered to unlock the drive. 
Now I get error status 27, I searched a lot to find about this error, but couldn't find the meaning of the error.

I want to take a full backup, reinstall a fresh OS X and then later I will format it again and restore my old system from the image.

---

Edit:
I now tried to take an image only of the user folder and got operation failed with status 107.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do I need to format the external backup to be able to take a disk image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Format of the partition must be Journaled to be able to make an image